# Reuse spock mock and inject into specification

Tags: mocking, spock

Switching from Mockito to Spock.

I want to create a reusable *spock* mock and inject it across multiple tests.

Besides using test instance members, fixture methods for mocking and stubbing, can I inject an already stubbed mock?

*Specification*

```
package com.cpg

import com.cpg.service.FooBarService
import org.spockframework.mock.MockUtil
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import spock.lang.Shared

class InjectableMockSpecification extends BaseSpecification {

    @Shared
    FooBarService injectedMockService

    def "invoke injected mock test"() {
        setup:
            assert injectedMockService != null
            new MockUtil().attachMock(injectedMockService, this)

        when:
            def response = injectedMockService.method("foo")

        then:
            response == "bar"

        cleanup:
            new MockUtil().detachMock(injectedMockService)
    }

    @Autowired
    void setMock(FooBarService mock) {
        this.injectedMockService = mock
    }
}
```

*Test configuration*

```
package com.cpg

import com.cpg.service.FooBarService
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.mock.DetachedMockFactory

@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = [TestConfig, MockConfig])
@WebAppConfiguration
class BaseSpecification extends Specification {

    @Configuration
    static class MockConfig {
        @Bean
        public FooBarService mock() {
            FooBarService mock = new DetachedMockFactory().Mock(FooBarService, name: "fooBarService")
            //is it posssible to perform stubbing here??
            //injectedMockService.method(_ as String) >> { return "bar" } //valid groovy, just triggers nullpointer on >> operator
            return mock
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

UPDATE:
    I inject a MockFactory class which can be injected and build stubs for me.

```
@Service
class UserManagerMockFactory extends Specification {

  UserManager getUserDetailsyByUserIdMock(String mockPath) {
    UserManager mock = Mock()
    UserDetails response = new UserDetails(new JsonSlurper().parse(new ClassPathResource(mockPath).inputStream))
    mock.getUserDetailsyByUserId(*_) >> response
    return mock
  }


   /**
   * Mock for three consecutive invocations.
   */
  UserManager getUsersMock() {
    UserManager manager = Mock()
    manager.getUsers(_) >>> [
        generate(10),        // page one with 10 users
        generate(10),       // page two with 10 users
        generateResponse(0)  // empty page
    manager
  }

  /**
   * Mock for throwable response.
   */
  UserManager getUserDetailsyByUserIdMockThrowingExceptionMock() {
    UserManager mockManager = Mock()
    mockManager.getUserDetailyByUserId(*_) >> { throw new UserNotFoundException() }
    mockManager
  }

}


// inject mock factory into specification class 
@Autowired
private UserManagerMockFactory userManagerMockFactory

// usage in Specification class    
def setup() {
this.testService.userManager = userManagerMockFactory.getUsersMock('mocks/userManager.testUser.json')
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what are your trying to accomplish? Why do you need a reusable mock? Why do you use MockUtil and DetachedMockFactory? What is wrong with the standard way of mocking things in Spock?

Comment: Mocked services represent the external dependencies my app depends on.
Some mocks are more complex than others. But when I mock a service once I dont want to do it over and over again inside each test (think code reuse). With all mocks being defined in a single file I can
readily inject them whenever and wherever I want without any duplication of code and optionally override them inside a given class if a more customized behavior is needed.

Comment: You reuse mocks easily either via extending a common testcase or via calling their creation methods by a common utility class. Same idea as "composition vs inheritance". There is no difference

Comment: Let me rephrase that. You can achieve code reuse of mocks very easily with standard inheritance and composition.  What is wrong with that approach?

Comment: Code organisation is not an issue here. My issue is the injection of spock mocked beans. A work around is to inject mockito mocks and use them inside spock assertions. Something I want to avoid.

Comment: Maybe I a missing something here, so please be patient with me. The standard way of mocking in Spock is to create a single mock, use it in a method, then in another method, create another mock and use it again. If the mock is the "same" you just have a parent class that creates it and thus you call common code in both methods. What is the issue with this approach? Why do you want a workaround? There is no injection needed and no need for Mockito mocks.

Comment: Or do you want something like this? https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/spock-subjects-collaborators-extension

Comment: Its a spring related thing. When using a test base class you have to manually wire everything together. For simpler components it may be an option but for complex services it becomes tedious.  Its simpler and more elegant to provide a configuration with mocked beans an let Spring DI handle the rest. Also if you don't use setter or constructor based injection how can you manually set the mocks from your base class. You can only use reflection to override private fields (thats to ugly).

Comment: I have already tested the  spock-subjects-collaborators-extension but it only works if collaborators are defined inside a particular spock test, you cannot inject collaborators between tests.

Comment: @Mandark I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal injecting stubs is a Spring framework thing not Spock thing. Instead I am injecting  POJO MockFactories which then build stubs for me.

Comment: Thanx for the update. :)